# How do I convert a set of lines that are not intersecting into a maintainable polygon (triangle)?

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, 3d

I have an application I'm working on that requires a fair amount of 3D graphics programming.  I have a series of lines that create both text and 3D cylindrical holes (see images).[image: Text][image]

I would like to be able to click and drag the objects in question using my mouse through the X,Y plane (Z constant).  My understanding is that in order for the bounding boxes to be setup correctly, I have to have everything in using 3D polygons (triangles).  I would like to be able to do collision detection without this conversion.  Is this possible?  If I must convert, can anyone point me to a piece of code that does this rather painlessly?

Comment: Another way of doing it is to have something called a "pick render", where you render your scene to an off-screen buffer giving each entity a different colour (or ID) you then get the pixel at the mouse position to work out what was hit (and from the mouse coordinates, where in space it was hit).

Answer (score 0):

You can treat each line segment as a cylinder, and check them for collision.
[Here's the math, as well as more alternatives](http://www.3dkingdoms.com/selection.html).